# Summarizing ratings for many products

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `project_product` and a table `project_consummation`. People consume a product, and may give the product a rating from 1 to 10.

Allow me some ASCII art for clarification:

```
+--------------------------+     +-------------------------+
| project_product          |     | project_consummation    |
|--------------------------|     |-------------------------|
| id   integer primary key |-\   | id integer primary key  |
| name varchar             |  \->| product_id integer      |
| ...                      |     | rating     integer      |
| various other fields...  |     | user_id    integer      |
+--------------------------+     | ...                     |
                                 | various other fields... |
                                 +-------------------------+
```

Now I want an overview of the votes for a product. Of course there can be `consummation`s without a `rating` value (e.g. NULL), so these have to be ignored.

The result should look like this (each rating from 1 to 10 should have its own column indicating the number of people who gave the product this rating, as well as the total number of ratings `num_ratings` and maybe later some median, standard deviation etc.):

```
 product_id | rating1 | rating2 | ... |rating10 | num_ratings 
------------+---------+---------+-----+---------+-------------
       1002 |         |         | ... |       1 |           1
       1014 |       4 |         | ... |       2 |           6
       1015 |       2 |       1 | ... |       1 |           4
```

I created a "solution" which is quite clumsy, because I do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for every rating column like this (I'll only show the first 3 columns, but I'm sure you'll see what a mess this becomes):

```
SELECT p.id AS product_id,
       rating1, rating2, rating3,
       COALESCE(rating1, 0) + COALESCE(rating2, 0) + COALESCE(rating3, 0) AS num_ratings
  FROM project_product p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
       ( SELECT product_id,
                count(*) AS rating1
           FROM project_consummation c
          WHERE rating = 1 
          GROUP BY product_id
       ) c1 ON p.id = c1.product_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
       ( SELECT product_id,
                count(*) AS rating2
           FROM project_consummation c
          WHERE rating = 2 
          GROUP BY product_id
       ) c2 ON p.id = c2.product_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
       ( SELECT product_id,
                count(*) AS rating3
           FROM project_consummation c
          WHERE rating = 3 
          GROUP BY product_id
       ) c3 ON p.id = c3.product_id
```

What would be a better solution regarding better code and especially better performance?

Comment: there are 2 more ways to do this, Using crosstab function, which will be a magnitude faster than your "clumsy" aproach and my other sugestion using case statements like "sum(case when rating = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as rating1, sum(case when rating = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as rating2 ...."

Comment: This looks like an interesting answer. Could you create a real answer from your comment?

Comment: I can, within half a hour ....bit busy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
select
        p.id product_id,
        count(case when c.rating = 1 then 1 else null end) rating1,
        count(case when c.rating = 2 then 1 else null end) rating2,
        count(case when c.rating = 3 then 1 else null end) rating3,
        count(case when c.rating = 4 then 1 else null end) rating4,
        count(case when c.rating = 5 then 1 else null end) rating5,
        count(case when c.rating = 6 then 1 else null end) rating6,
        count(case when c.rating = 7 then 1 else null end) rating7,
        count(case when c.rating = 8 then 1 else null end) rating8,
        count(case when c.rating = 9 then 1 else null end) rating9,
        count(case when c.rating = 10 then 1 else null end) rating10,
        count(c.rating) num_ratings
    from project_product p
    left join project_consummation c on c.product_id = p.id
        group by p.id
        order by p.id;
```

or a bit shorter form for ratings:

```
select
            p.id product_id,
            count(nullif(c.rating = 1, false)) rating1,
            count(nullif(c.rating = 2, false)) rating2,
            count(nullif(c.rating = 3, false)) rating3,
            count(nullif(c.rating = 4, false)) rating4,
            count(nullif(c.rating = 5, false)) rating5,
            count(nullif(c.rating = 6, false)) rating6,
            count(nullif(c.rating = 7, false)) rating7,
            count(nullif(c.rating = 8, false)) rating8,
            count(nullif(c.rating = 9, false)) rating9,
            count(nullif(c.rating = 10, false)) rating10,
            count(c.rating) num_ratings
        from project_product p
        left join project_consummation c on c.product_id = p.id
            group by p.id
            order by p.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

not perfect ... but hope you get the idea

using case

```
SELECT project_product.id,project_product.name 
     , sum(case when rating = 1 then 1 else 0 end ) as rating1
     , sum(case when rating = 2 then 1 else 0 end ) as rating2
     , sum(case when rating = 3 then 1 else 0 end ) as rating3
     , sum(case when rating = 4 then 1 else 0 end ) as rating4
     , sum(case when rating = 5 then 1 else 0 end ) as rating5
     , sum(case when rating = 6 then 1 else 0 end ) as rating6
     , sum(case when rating = 7 then 1 else 0 end ) as rating7
     , sum(case when rating = 8 then 1 else 0 end ) as rating8
     , sum(case when rating = 9 then 1 else 0 end ) as rating9
     , sum(case when rating = 10 then 1 else 0 end ) as rating10
  FROM project_product 
  LEFT JOIN project_consummation ON (project_product.id = project_consummation.product_id)
  GROUP BY project_product.id, project_product.name
```

and using crosstab :

```
-- if necessary:
-- CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;

SELECT project_product.id,
       rating1, rating2, rating3, rating4, rating5,
       rating6, rating7, rating8, rating9, rating10, 
       rating1+rating2+rating3+rating4+rating5+
       rating6+rating7+rating8+rating9+rating10 as num_ratings
  FROM project_product
  LEFT JOIN crosstab(
       'select product_id, rating, count(*)
          from project_consummation
         group by product_id, rating
         order by product_id, rating ',
       'select generate_series(1, 10)')
       AS main (
         id integer, rating1 integer, rating2 integer, rating3 integer,
         rating4 integer, rating5 integer, rating6 integer,
         rating7 integer, rating8 integer, rating9 integer, rating10 integer
       )  ON (project_product.id = main.id )
```